# Complex-step not working as expected in OpenMDAO component

Tags: openmdao

I'm trying to use complex-step to obtain the derivatives of a simple component in OpenMDAO. Although I have the analytic derivatives, I want to compare performance with complex-step. This is part of a larger design problem.

Here is a minimal example:

```
import numpy as np
from openmdao.api import IndepVarComp, Component, Problem, Group

class SpatialBeamDisp(Component):

    def __init__(self, ny):
        super(SpatialBeamDisp, self).__init__()

        self.ny = ny

        self.add_param('disp_aug', val=np.zeros(((self.ny+1)*6), dtype='complex'))
        self.add_output('disp', val=np.zeros((self.ny, 6), dtype='complex'))

        # Comment out this line to use analytic derivatives
        self.deriv_options['type'] = 'cs'

    def solve_nonlinear(self, params, unknowns, resids):
        # Obtain the relevant portions of disp_aug and store the reshaped
        # displacements in disp
        unknowns['disp'] = params['disp_aug'][:-6].reshape((self.ny, 6))

    def linearize(self, params, unknowns, resids):
        jac = self.alloc_jacobian()
        n = self.ny * 6
        jac['disp', 'disp_aug'] = np.hstack((np.eye((n)), np.zeros((n, 6))))
        return jac

top = Problem()

root = top.root = Group()

n = 5

disp_aug = np.random.random(((n+1) * 6))

root.add('disp_input', IndepVarComp('disp_aug', disp_aug), promotes=['*'])

root.add('disp_', SpatialBeamDisp(n), promotes=['*'])

top.setup()
top.run_once()
top.check_partial_derivatives(compact_print=True)
```

Running this code as-is produces an incorrect Jacobian, while commenting out the `self.deriv_options['type' = 'cs'` line and using the analytic expression produces the correct Jacobian.

I am using OpenMDAO 1.7.3 and numpy 1.10.2 on Ubuntu.

Am I setting up the complex-step derivatives incorrectly? If so, how should I write this component to be complex-step capable?

Comment: I have solved this problem for my purposes by getting rid of the reshape line and replacing it with an explicit assignment loop, though I still feel like the original code show have worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is a memory/pointer related problem. Essentially, when you did the slice and reshape you ended up with a view into the original array, which you then assigned to `unknowns['disp']`. This assignment broke OpenMDAO's pointer to the original data it was using to do the complex-step calculations. You can fix it explicitly by changing the assignment to ask for a copy of the data into the current memory location instead:

```
def solve_nonlinear(self, params, unknowns, resids):
    # Obtain the relevant portions of disp_aug and store the reshaped
    # displacements in disp
    unknowns['disp'][:] = params['disp_aug'][:-6].reshape((self.ny, 6))
```

There must be an underlying bug in the CS code of OpenMDAO that is making this assignment protection necessary though. The issue does not show up for fd, only cs.